# Flip transition between storyboard view controllers not working

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm having a lot of trouble setting a flip transition between storyboards. The app crashes when the method below is called. I'm getting the error message:

`[NSPathStore2 setView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance...`

This is my code:

```
- (void)advanceToNextViewController {

    humptyDumptyViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstStoryVC"];
     /*
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    */
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO]; 
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO]; 
    [UIView commitAnimations];


}
```

I'd appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using storyboard. This is more accurate, try this:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstStoryVC"];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

But be sure to name your view's `identifier` "**firstStoryVC**" otherwise it will crash and wont work.

Then when you want to dimiss the view:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one , it will give you full control over timings and animation.

```
humptyDumptyViewController *controller = [self.storyboardinstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstStoryVC"];
[UIView  beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```